# iPad Air sold online as new: how can I be certain?

Tags: ipad

I purchased an iPad Air 1, online from a reputable "group discount" website. Though the site sells certified refurbished and used Apple products, this product clearly stated "brand new". It arrived in the shrink wrapped Apple box and once opened,looked legitimately packaged new. I'm skeptible by nature, however felt questionable when noticed there was no manual or earbuds included. There was a new Apple charger in the box. Additionally,it arrived 100 % charged. (?) I recall having to charge every wireless purchase ever made!
  I'm not technically challenged, familiar to older iPads,and have purchased many Apple products in the past. However, they have always included an Apple manual,ear buds and it required to be fully charged. I had no problem registering the pad or assigning a password,however I want to be certain what I purchased is as advertised; Brand new and in perfect working condition. The product has a 30 day, no question, return policy and a one year Apple warrantee. Can anyone confirm how their iPad air appeared apon opening, what was included, did it require charging, and how can I scan it for prior use or refurburshing?

Answer (score 1):

My iPad Air did not include earbuds - I don't think any iPad model has even included earbuds.

As far as I can remember, every iPad I have bought from Apple has been received ready to turn on. If not 100% charged, then 80% charged or similar.

iPads do not come with a big manual at all. There's a little booklet with a few "cards" that explain the buttons on the iPad - that's really all.

So all in all, none of those observations should lead you to conclude that your iPad was not new when you purchased it.

To be sure, I would go to the Apple Support site and check your warranty status with your serial number.